# .htaccess get variable redirect resulting in 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, server-error

I've read through the other posts pertaining to this topic and still haven't found my solution.

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]

ErrorDocument 404 https://website.com/page/404

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index /$1 [R=301,L]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Whenever I navigate to https://website.com/page/profile/name/ I receive a 500 internal server error.

The other conditions seem to be working properly however this one in particular is not.

Comment: Is your htaccess file located in the `/page` dir?

Comment: @AmitVerma it's located under public_html

Comment: @AmitVerma located directly under public_html i meant to say, page is a direct child of public_html

Comment: @AmitVerma I've since rewrittten another .htaccess and put it in the page directory. This .htaccess only contains the line pertaining to profile. This makes the page work, however, it makes every other page a 404 error. Any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

This can not work :

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

you must define the variable with this : (.*)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host}          "!^$" [NC]
RewriteRule "^profile/(.*).php$"   "profile.php?username=$1"       [NC,L,QSA]
```

after this you can check the regex.